# Android Studio: MediaPlayer Controller in Webview app

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

Im currently create a webview app using android studio. Im looking for the best solution to let users pause, play, stop mp3 files while using other apps by a MediaPlayer Controller in the notification bar like Spotify etc..

Answer (score 0):

This is quite involved due to the complexity of the several stages of the development process. This [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app.html) may help you get started that guides you through the processes involved. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try this today!